# Graph API not allowing online meetings

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am currently setting up a web page where users can send event requests to others using the Microsoft Graph api. I would like users to be able to send an online meeting request and then provide the options of ms teams and Skype.

However as soon as I add the property 'isOnlineMeeting' and/or 'onlineMeetingProvider' I will always return an error 400 with a bad request. This is because the property doesn't exist on the /me/events.

[image: Text]
(the response)

I have no idea why however, currently I am using the microsoft graph explorer to test the request.

I have made sure that every permission is needed to send an invite:

- Calendar.Read
- Calendar.Read.Shared
- Calendar.ReadWrite
- Calendar.ReadWrite.Shared

If a meeting is sent without these properties it works fine. I have created other personal outlook accounts and it works as expected with this property. I have asked other people in my org to try too and theirs works fine.

Does this mean that my ms account is broken in some way? if so how could I fix it in order to send this request.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
            var body= "{email body};
            var string = "{\"subject\": \"Join the Teams Meeting\", \"body\": {\"contentType\": \"HTML\",  \"content\": \"" + body + "\" }, \"start\": {\"dateTime\": \"2020-09-28T19:30:34\",\"timeZone\": \"Pacific Standard Time\" }, \"end\": { \"dateTime\": \"2020-09-28T20:00:34\", \"timeZone\": \"Pacific Standard Time\"}, \"location\":{ \"displayName\":\"Team meeting\"  },  \"attendees\": [ { \"emailAddress\": {     \"address\":\"xxxx@in.xxx.com\", \"name\": \"xxxx xxxx\" }, \"type\": \"required\" } ],\"allowNewTimeProposals\": \"true\"}";
            client = new RestClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events");
            request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);         
            request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            request.AddHeader("accept-language", "en");
            request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");            
            request.AddParameter("application/json", string, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            response = client.Execute(request);
```

To generate token:

```
            var client = new RestClient("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-Id}/oauth2/v2.0/token");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);         
            request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");         
            request.AddHeader("grant_type", "password");
            request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "grant_type=password&client_id={client-Id}&client_secret={client-secret}&scope={scopeurl}&userName={username}&password={password}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            var json = response.Content;
            var JSONObject = JObject.Parse(json);
            var token = (string)JSONObject["access_token"];
```